# Magento 2 base price with currency

Tags: magento-2.1, price, currency

I will try to explain as much as I can.

**Take note:**

We use the website as a view site only and no checkout is complete with the website. We use magento because it give us good module and easy configuration.

**Here is our problem:**

We already use magento 1 with our website and we want to upgrade for magento 2.

In magento 1, we have 1 store and 3 language (french - Canada | English - Canada | English - USA ), As for now the customer price is in CAD for Canada and in USD for USA.

**Here is our configuration:**

In the price section, we have an attribute that we can change currency depend on the product if we buy in USA or CAD and we choose the good one. When we have choose the good currency, we insert the base price and we have a third attribute, price.

**So here is the configuration:**

Base price currency -> USD or CAD
Base price -> Customer pricing
Price -> The base price changing with currency that we have choose

The default currency for our store is CAD, so when we choose CAD in the base price currency, the price will show same price as no change have been done, but when the base price currency is in USD, the price will be change with the day currency and will be auto updated each time magento currency will do.

Can someone help me to have this working with Magento 2 please?

It is an extension for Magento 1 and the company that have made this does not exist anymore.

Thanks in advance!